# Chrome doesn't render fonts in PDFs

Tags: linux, google-chrome, pdf

My Google Chrome isn't rendering fonts correctly, mainly in PDFs.

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jwGW.png)

The text simply doesn't appear. I'm using Manjaro Linux and Chrome 79.0.3945.88.

Answer (score -1):

You can fix the text tuner on start menu. Type ' adjust clear type text' in search box and check the box below 'clear type '.  Then click next and finish. 
 You can reinstall your font in your browser.  Just uninstall the third party font like " Alien league tech"  and install " ariel" font. Or u can reboot your browser after uninstall the third party fonts.